# animejs in angular is not animating

Tags: angular, anime.js

I am trying to use animejs in Angular4 project.
I have been looking for some hint and clue online how to proceed with this, but there is barely nothing anywhere.

So I am trying to move box along x coordinates...

animejs-logo.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import anime from 'animejs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-animejs-logo',
  templateUrl: './animejs-logo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./animejs-logo.component.scss']
})
export class AnimejsLogoComponent {
  animation = anime({
    targets: ['.box'],
    translateX: [
      { value: 500, duration: 1000 },
      { value: 0, duration: 1000 }
    ],
    duration: 2000,
    loop: true
  });

  animate() {
    console.log('play');
    this.animation.play();
  }
}
```

animejs-logo.component.scss:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 4px;
}
.red { background-color: #f00; }
.green { background-color: #0f0; }
.blue { background-color: #00f; }
```

animejs-logo.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <button (click)="animate()">Play</button>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is nothing special or incredible. First try with the animejs... 
Can please someone explain me what I am doing wrong? Why it doesn't fire up? 
I am not having any errors in console, project's compiling.

Answer (score 12):

OK, solved.

Issue was that I defined anime objects in wrong moment of lifecycle... 
It turned out that all elements must be rendered and after that one can define animations. So, all definitions are in the `ngAfterViewInit` e.g.:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.square = anime({
        targets: '#animation_1 .animate',
        translateX: [
            { value: 250, duration: 1000 },
            { value: 0, duration: 1000 }
        ],
        duration: 2000,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false
   });
}
```

Comment: I was trying to click a button to display and then slide an absolute div over a form.  Animation wasn't working bc the elements weren't there.  This answer helped me solve it.  Thanks!

Comment: You are a legend, thank you so much! It works!